# Is STM32f429 discovery board fully supported on qemu?

Tags: embedded, emulation, qemu

I'm trying to emulate STM32F429I discovery board using qemu & eclipse IDE. I got the blinky example running with the led turning on and off on the graphics screen but I have tried an example to run the on-board screen and it doesn't seem to be running, Is it supported? Also, many drivers fail when simulated with qemu (sdram, rcc, ...) How can I know exactly what peripherals that are fully supported?

Here's the part of documentation about the board, What is meant by "FP not emulated" anyway?
[image]

Comment: FP stands for "floating point".